# Не заканчиваются асинхронно-выполняемые Task-и (Gulp 4)

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, task

Таск, вызывающий:

```
gulp.task('dev:build', () => {
    gulp.parallel('dev:html', 'dev:css', 'dev:js');
});
```

Таски, выполняемые:

```
gulp.task('dev:html', () => {
   gulp.src(`${PATHS.source}/**/*.html`, { since: gulp.lastRun('dev:html') })
    .pipe(newer(PATHS.build))
    .pipe(htmlhint())
    .pipe(htmlhint.reporter())
    .pipe(htmlhint.failOnError())
    .pipe(debug({ title: 'HTML Built' }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(PATHS.build));
});
gulp.task('dev:css', () => {
   gulp.src(`${PATHS.source}/scss/*.*`, { since: gulp.lastRun('dev:css') })
    .pipe(newer(PATHS.build))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(sass().on('error', notifier.onError({
      message: '<%= error.message %>',
      title: 'SASS Error',
      sound: 'frog',
    })))
    .pipe(debug({ title: 'CSS Compiled' }))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(`${PATHS.build}/css`));
});
gulp.task('dev:js', () => {
   gulp.src(`${PATHS.source}/js/*.js`)
    .pipe(jsEslint())
    .pipe(jsEslint.format())
    .pipe(jsEslint.failAfterError())
    .on('error', notifier.onError({
      title: 'JS Linting Fail',
      message: '<%= error.message %>',
    }))
    .pipe(jsPolyfills('polyfills.js', {
      browsers: '> 1%',
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(`${PATHS.build}/js`));
});
```

Итог выполнения:

```
[12:25:54] The following tasks did not complete: dev:build
[12:25:54] Did you forget to signal async completion?
```

Что можно сделать с этим? Как исправить?

Comment: Попробуйте `return gulp.src...`

Comment: Невероятно, но помогло это и:
    `gulp.task('dev:build', gulp:series(
        gulp.parallel('dev:html', 'dev:css', 'dev:js')
    ));`

Answer (score 0):

Смог почти самостоятельно все сделать как надо.

1) Перед каждым `gulp.src..` вставть `return`. Получилось `return gulp.src` (спасибо товарищу [bleser](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/184903/bleser))

2) Изменил объявление, и вместо Function Expression объявляю `gulp.series`, внутри которого уже объявляю `gulp.parallel`:

```
gulp.task('dev:build', gulp:series( 
    gulp.parallel('dev:html', 'dev:css', 'dev:js') 
));
```